# How to get owl carousel owl-nav outside the div

Tags: owl-carousel

i want to get owl carousel owl-nav outside the div
Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 2
    },
    600: {
      items: 2
    },
    1000: {
      items: 2
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel.owl-theme .slide {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-theme .slide img {
  width: auto;
}

.slide-text {
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: -30%;
  color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0!important;
  background: #fff!important;
  border: 2px solid tomato!important;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next {
  right: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next:hover,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev:hover {
  background: tomato!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.2/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      <div class="slide-text">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      <div class="slide-text">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      <div class="slide-text">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      <div class="slide-text">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
      <div class="slide-text">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much I want arrows edge of body left and right hope you understand please help

Comment: Sanoja Weerakon Updated answer